# Azure Functions host was shutdown when an error occurs

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-webjobs

An error has occurred in my function app and it was shutdown. "Singleton lock renewal failed for blob

```py
with error code 409: LeaseIdMismatchWithLeaseOperation. The last successful renewal completed at 2023-12-15T20:43:56.694Z (130861 milliseconds ago) with a duration of 6 milliseconds. The lease period was 60000 milliseconds."
```

And then it logged this error and was shutdown

```
"An unhandled exception has occurred. Host is shutting down."
```

This occurred in executing a timer trigger function. How can we prevent the host from shutting down when this or any other error happens? Is there a way to catch the exceptions that occur in host? ***I am using functions version 2.x.***

I am just looking to prevent the app from shutdown/crashing.

Answer (score 0):

In order to resolve 409 errors with the Function app, Make sure you use different storage accounts for different Function Apps. When the same storage account is shared between 2 or more functions they all write to the same storage account blob and leases. In order to avoid this error:-

Refer this [**Github comment**](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/issues/1864#issuecomment-764423560) by ThomasArdal

- Make sure you use different storage account to avoid this collision.
- Explicitly specify the host ID of the Function in the Functions    settings like below:-

[image]

[image]

Also, Try implementing these setting to make the singleton behaviour successful in your Function app:-

[host.json reference for Azure Functions 2.x | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-host-json#singleton)

```json
{
    "singleton": {
      "lockPeriod": "00:00:10",
      "listenerLockPeriod": "00:02:00",
      "listenerLockRecoveryPollingInterval": "00:01:00",
      "lockAcquisitionTimeout": "00:02:00",
      "lockAcquisitionPollingInterval": "00:00:02"
    }
}
```